# Dynamic Row Height for DataTable in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, datatable

I'm new to flutter.

I have a Datatable with data, but not all data is the same length, some are bigger than others. So my question is, can the height of the rows be made dynamic to fit the length of the data?

I know that there is a dataRowHeight property, but if I adjust it to show the longest data, the small ones have a very noticeable white space and it does not work for me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 8):

Here is simple solution.

Give `infinity` height to `dataRowMaxHeight`

```
dataRowMaxHeight: double.infinity, // For dynamic row content height.
```

Example

```
DataTable(
  dataRowMaxHeight: double.infinity,
  columns: const [
    // Your column data
    DataColumn(label: Text("Column Heading")),
  ],
  rows: [
    DataCell(
      SizedBox(
      width: 100, // <- Give Here width of column as per your need.
      child: Text(
         "Long text here",
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you didn't share any code. but you can use expanded inside rows and columns.

```
Row(children:[Expanded(child: yourWidget),])
```